# Time change for Brownian Motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

It is well known that any Itô local martingale of the form $dX_t=Y_sdB_s$ with the initial condition that $X_0=0$ and $Y_s$ being adapted, continuous, and locally square integrable can be reparametrized as a Brownian motion by defining:
$$\tau_t:= \inf\{s \geq 0: \int_0^s Y_u^2du = t\}$$
And we have that the process $X_{\tau_t}$ is a Brownian motion (with a suitable change of filtration). Is it possible to do the same where $Y_s$ exhibits finite time blowup? Specifically if $\lim_{t \to \infty}\tau_t <\infty$ with positive probability. Does the same method work?

The context of this problem is that my lecturer vaguely remarked about the existence of such theorems and I am trying to find a reference for this. My guess is that this is provable with the Levy characterization of Brownian motion, but I have yet to make too much progress on that. So I am asking to see if anyone knows of such a theorem and if so could they please provide a source (I am not asking help to prove this for myself and I just want to see if this is written somewhere).

Comment: The result is known as Dubins-Schwarz theorem, so you might want to search for that. But I wonder right now, why this should not work. It says **local** martingale. Isn't $dX_t=-\ln(1-t)dB_t$ a legit example you are looking for? (I'm not sure though, anyone please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yes I’m asking for if similar results hold if we relax the condition that it is a local martingale. Suppose the same setup, say $dX_s=Y_sdB_s$ but we do not require $\int_0^tY_s^2ds$ to be finite.

Comment: What I trying to say is, that you do not need to relax anything for this. I wanted to state the example $dM_t=\frac{1}{1-t}dB_t$ for $t\in[0,1)$. In this case $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}dt=\infty$ and if I am not mistaken $(M_t)_{t\in[0,1)}$ is a local martingale and Dubin-Schwarz applies. The idea of the theorem is, that the time horizons can be streched or compressed according to the stopping times. In the example above, for a very big $t\in[0,\infty)$ you get the time $\tau_t\in[0,1)$ and the Brownian motion $B_t:=M_{\tau_t}$.

Comment: Note, that you cannot really define a stochastic integral beyond a time $t$ with $P( \int_0^t Y_s^2ds =\infty)>0$. At a bigger time than $t$, it would not be a $L^2$ random variable by the Itô isometry.

Comment: Okay wait I think my understanding is lacking in something basic. For our definition of a local martingale in our class, we have a localizing sequence of stopping times $\tau_n:= \inf\{t \geq 0: <X>_t \geq n\}$, such that $\tau_n \to \infty$ almost surely. Do you not require the stopping times to tend to infinity?

Comment: Yes, that is a fair point. In this case $(M_t)_{t\in[0,1)}$ can at most be only a martingale. But doesn't this mean, that your desired result cannot hold for local martingales in the first place? Because $P(\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\tau_t<\infty)>0$ and $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tau_n=\infty)=1$ are contradictory, since $\langle X \rangle_t=\int_0^tY_s^2ds$. (Your stopping time $\tau_t$ is defined the same as in your localizing sequence.)

Comment: So maybe what you want is that it works for finite time horizon martingales, where the quadratic variation is infinity at the time horizon. And I think this should be already fine with the original Dubins-Schwarz theorem?

Comment: Okay I see what’s going on, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky issue because in order to even define stochastic integration at time $t=T$

$$M_{t}=\int_{0}^{T} Y_{s}dB_{s},$$

we need to have existence of the expected quadratic variation i.e. $E[\langle M\rangle_{T}]<\infty$. For example, in Shreve-Karatzas problem 4.11 section 3.4, the integral $\int^{1}_{0}X_{s}dB_{s}$ is undefined on the event

$$E:=\left\{ \int^{1}_{0}X_{s}^{2}ds=+\infty  \right\}.$$

So instead in order to apply the Dubins-Schwarz theorem for local martingales ([Time-Changed Brownian Motion](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/))

> Theorem 1 Any continuous local martingale X with $X_0=0$ is a continuous time-change of standard Brownian motion (possibly under an enlargement of the probability space).

we need to truncate in some way eg. $X_{s}:=Y_{s}\wedge M$.